# Codeigniter: Query is returning all rows in table on select/like statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm following this tutorial on creating a live search feature: [http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/live-search-using-jquery-ajax-php-codeigniter-and-mysql)

and my query in the model is returning all rows in the table. This is my query:

```
$query = $this->db->select('Key, FirstName, LastName, CompanyName')
                      ->like('FirstName', $search, 'both')
                      ->or_like('LastName', $search, 'both')
                      ->or_like('CompanyName', $search, 'both')
                      ->where('Deleted', 0)
                      ->from('AMOwners')
                      ->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

I would like to type a whole/partial of a name or company name and have it checked against three columns to see if there is a match. But when the jquery function is triggered to start polling the database, it always pulls all the rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: explore your question jquery call function. controller.etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write a nested query which contains `AND` and `OR` statements:

```
$query = $this->db->select('Key, FirstName, LastName, CompanyName')
                  ->where('Deleted', 0)
                  ->where("(FirstName LIKE '%$search%' OR LastName LIKE '%$search%' OR CompanyName LIKE '%$search%')")
                  ->from('AMOwners')
                  ->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: I did some more testing by making a direct route to that controller/method and having it print directly to the page and the query is pulling the right information now. How can I check the json response?

Comment: Jason, I'd suggest to write a new question - its related, but not part of the original question. Also the tags would be different.

Comment: @Vickel, I know that question did you answer a time ago, but why didn´t work the or_like?

Comment: @Mary I think at the time, we used CI 2.x, there was no possibility to group like and or_like within a where clause, except of using my example. With CI 3.0 you can use Query Grouping to achieve this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=group#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

select messages_id, message, CASE WHEN message_from_type='patient' THEN (select first_name from patients where patient_id=message_from_id) ELSE (select full_name from admin_user where admin_user_id=message_from_id) END  as from_name, CASE WHEN message_to_type='patient' THEN (select first_name from patients where patient_id=message_to_id) ELSE (select full_name from admin_user where admin_user_id=message_to_id) END as to_name  from messages;

Comment: Please format the code